# Don't pre-populate any site when submitting a question from the feed view in the android app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, asking-questions, android-app, android-app-feed

A couple of times I've been using the app and posted a question to stackoverflow when I meant to post to meta. Silly me; it was late and I was tired.

---

If we tap to create a question while viewing the Feed in the android app, I don't think it should pre-populate the Site field with any site. You should have to select it, rather than it defaulting to the site you have the most reputation on.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily default to Stack Overflow, but to the site that you have the most reputation on. We'll discuss this.

Comment: Only just seen this; thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the pay off here is worth it. The site selector defaults to the site you have the most reputation on, or the last site you posted to in the app (if any) unless you're coming to it directly from looking at a specific site. Removing the first two logic steps here and making it default to empty unless you come in from a specific site seems like a step back in functionality to me since you're most likely going to be posting to the site the application picked.